# Using Google Daydream keyboard in VR mode for text input in canvas(for Daydream app)

Tags: canvas, unity-game-engine, keyboard, daydream

Recently, I have seen many posts about changes in Google daydream keyboard App. I have a login scene in my daydream app. Right now, I show that scene in non-VR mode, as I don't have a way to show keyboard in VR mode. Is there a way to use daydream keyboard in my Daydream app(VR mode), so that I can put that login canvas scene in VR mode? I have seen earlier post [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40614674/google-daydream-keyboard-unity-ui-textinput) saying it can't be done till now. But now, as there are new updates, can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, now you can use the daydream keyboard (used in YouTube Daydream app). The GoogleVR SDK now provides the prefab for the keyboard too. Download the GoogleVR SDK, under the directory Demos/Scenes, you will find the demo for Keyboard. Enjoy!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked well in my phone. Although in unity3d engine, I got this error screen saying "Controller connecting..." in the input field. My controller is connected to laptop. Please help me if you know how to fix it. It will be really helpful for fast development.

Comment: Which medium are you using for connecting the controller to Unity. USB or Wifi?

Comment: The message "Controller connecting", should not appear if you are entering correct IP in EmulatorConfig file (i.e. your controller is getting connected).

Comment: I had connected the real daydream controller to the PC using bluetooth.